# On which thread is a Swift property's didSet{} being executed?

Tags: multithreading, swift, closures

I have defined a property in Swift like:

```
var foo : String {
  didSet {
    doSomething()
  }
}
```

So everytime I set `foo` like `foo = "bar"` my `didSet` will be executed.

However I can not find out **on which thread** `didSet` is being executed.

For example what happens in this case:

```
dispatch_async(some_queue, { () -> Void in
     self.foo = "bar"
})
```

This will cause the `didSet` code to be executed. Will `didSet` be run on `some_queue` or always on the `main_queue`?

Comment: You can use `NSThread.isMainThread()` in `didSet` to find out on what thread the program is running there. And if you use `dispatch_async(some_queue....` for setting that property, it has to be called on `some_queue`

Comment: I know how to force a queue. I just wanted to know about the default behaviour.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The property observers `willSet` and `didSet` are *directly* called from within the setter method, immediately
before/after the new value is stored, so all this executes on the same thread.

You can verify that by setting a breakpoint in `didSet` and inspecting
the stack backtrace, which would look like this:

```
* thread #2: tid = 0x4df3, 0x000000010024f9eb swtest2`swtest2.foo.didset : Swift.String(oldValue="foo") + 27 at main.swift:6, queue = 'myQueue', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x000000010024f9eb swtest2`swtest2.foo.didset : Swift.String(oldValue="foo") + 27 at main.swift:6
    frame #1: 0x000000010024fb91 swtest2`swtest2.foo.setter : Swift.String(newValue="bar") + 177 at main.swift:4
    frame #2: 0x000000010024fe3a swtest2`swtest2.(closure #1) + 42 at main.swift:13
    ...
```

Comment: Interesting information actually.  I had been thinking of using the NSThread class to learn a bit how multithreading behaves in iOS.  Would you know how to achieve the same result using such class?